# Aligning alternating items to different places in a container with CSS positioning via flexbox or grid?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

[image]

Is it possible to layout the following markup to be like the linked screenshot? Of course it would be easy to rearrange the HTML, but how might I start to approach it with only CSS?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>

  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>

  <div class="foo"></div>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</div>
```

This CSS doesn't quite get there, but it's close (sort of).

```
.container{
  width: 60%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #ddd;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}
.foo, .bar {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.foo{
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #555;
  align-self: flex-start;
}
.bar{
  width: 450px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: gray;
  align-self: flex-end;
  order: 2;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/joeashworth/h90nc2qL/3/

Comment: Not with Flexbox or CSS-Grid (I think) since they create *rows* by default. You would need to rethink the structure. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/ajaOLe

Answer (score 0):

I know you mentioned not wanting to change the HTML but this is how I would go about creating this layout.

```css
.container{
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .boxed {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
  .foo, .bar {
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .foo{
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #555;
    align-self: flex-start;
  }
  .foo-2 {
    margin-top: -60px;
  }
  .foo-3 {
    margin-top: -120px;
  }
  .bar{
    width: 450px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: gray;
    align-self: flex-end;
    order: 2;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="boxed">
      <div class="foo foo-1"></div>
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxed">
      <div class="foo foo-2"></div>
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="boxed">
      <div class="foo foo-3"></div>
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Like @Paulie_D mentioned above, I believe the structure needs changing.  I think this should be the accepted answer.